# What is best way to over 100 data Select Box Field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm beiginer. now I understand how to make select box. like below. 
I would like to make Another select box field that are products name.
its about 100 product very long.
What is Smart and best way to add many data into  index.blade.php ?
I would like to it to independent file.

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('age') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

     <p>Age</p>


     {{ Form::select('age', ['Under 18', '19 to 30', 'Over 30']) }}

          <div class="col-sm-10">                                
             @if ($errors->has('age'))
                 <span class="help-block">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('age') }}</strong>
                 </span>
             @endif
          </div>
@endsection
```

this is list example

```
a1234
b1254
c546
d6467
e8952
f84664
g45646
h46546
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create another blade like `select_products.blade.php`
in it, you could have something like:

```
{{ Form::select('products', $productsArray) }}
```

You can use the `pluck` method to get the array in the right format.Like this:

```
$productsArray = ProductModel::all()->pluck('name', 'id)->all();
```

Ideally it should be done before sending data to the view (in you controller probably)

And you could use Blade's @include directive to call `select_products.blade.php`

- [More on pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)
- [More on Blade's include](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views)

Hope it helps, o/

---

You could also use something like [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) for better UX considering its a lot of products

Comment: Thank you so much Renato Gomes. it was amazing answer!! I liked very much select2. Thank you! you made my day!

Comment: nice to be helpful @machagr . Upvote my answer if you can :D

Answer (score 0):

use [@foreach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops) in Blade

```
<select name="product">
    @foreach($products as $product)

       <option value="{{$option->id}}">{{$option->name}}</option>

    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mahdi Younesi  I see foreach ! now I have another question. I add product list  above.  Could you tell me how to write above products list to where? what filename? this blade file is child . so another child file can stay this file?